# Running Periodic Task

Tags: c#, task, periodic-task

I'm developing a c# application that periodically sends message to a device.

First question : What is the best way to run a function that sends message periodically (every 1 second)?

Second question : Sometimes I want to stop periodic request, run a block of code, and start periodic request again.
What is the best way to implement this mechanism?

It's clear that periodic request should run in another thread.

Before running "a block of code", stopping periodic request and starting again at the end of code block might be a solution but I want to implement something smart on periodic request side.

Comment: Why not to use `timer` ?

Comment: Timer can be a solution, I just asked what is the best way?

Comment: what do you mean by "something smart" ? What did you try ? Post your code !

Answer (score 0):

**First question**: You want a thread. Inside the thread you want an infinite loop. Then an `if` statement checking a timer.

**Second question**: Then you want a [**semaphore**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx) inside that loop. The semaphore will block the the code for you and then awaken it once you are ready.

---

```
   while(true)
   {
      check semaphore

      if one second has passed 
         then send message.
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a Window Service. Window service will solve your problem. Check these links.

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/06/creating-windows-service-in-c-or.html

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14353/Creating-a-Basic-Windows-Service-in-C

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The [Threading Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swx5easy.aspx) is what you should look at